# base class for all exception in PHP

Tags: java, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, exception

I wanted to know base class for all exception in PHP, just like we have `EXCEPTION` class in java and all classes are inherited from it,The reason I want to know is while I am working on `facebook` app in php , I want to catch all `FBAPIEXCEPTION` in that class object,

```
try {
            $accesstoken = $facebook->getAccessToken();
            $userData= $facebook->api('/me', 'GET' ,array ('access_token' => $accesstoken));
            $email= $facebook->api('/me?fields=email', 'GET' ,array ('access_token' => $accesstoken));
            }
            catch(Exception  $e) {

                return false;

      }
```

so if any exception occur , I could catch that.

Comment: All exceptions in PHP extend from the `Exception` class

Comment: @MarkBaker even the one from Facebook , LI right?

Comment: If it's a exception for a PHP library, then it shouldn't be any different to any other PHP exception.... only Exceptions can be thrown... Quoting from the manual - `A User defined Exception class can be defined by extending the built-in Exception class.`

Comment: Looking at the code for http://fbpost.googlecode.com/hg/inc/common.php?r=0a0dc79067866f6de52f920030e22ebd9a4add04 ... `class FBApiException extends Exception`